# Is it possible to run the hector_quadrotor demos in kinetic?

Tags: catkin-make, hector-quadrotor, ros-kinetic, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed the kinetic following the Debian instructions.

I found the hector_quadrotor indoor slam tutorial here:
http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo

I tried installing `ros-hydro-hector-quadrotor-demo`, but that package was not found.  I tried following the `wstool` instructions, however when I ran `catkin_make` I got the output listed below (I'm not sure how to make it more concise):

```
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawMagnetic
Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_YawrateCommand
Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ServoCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RC
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RuddersCommand
Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Compass
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AttitudeCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ThrustCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawImu
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Supply
Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorStatus
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Altimeter
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelocityXYCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawRC
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorPWM
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelocityZCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PositionXYCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeightCommand
[  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeadingCommand
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _hector_uav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ControllerState
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetDistanceToObstacle
[  0%] Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetRobotTrajectory
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetNormal
Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetSearchPosition
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetRecoveryInfo
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target hector_quadrotor_aerodynamics
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target map_to_image_node
[  0%] Built target _driver_base_generate_messages_check_deps_ConfigString
[  0%] Built target _driver_base_generate_messages_check_deps_ConfigValue
[  0%] Built target _driver_base_generate_messages_check_deps_SensorLevels
[  0%] [  0%] Building CXX object hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o
[  1%] Built target hector_gazebo_plugins_gencfg
[  2%] Building CXX object hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.cpp.o
Built target gazebo_ros_force_based_move
[  2%] Built target hector_gazebo_reset_plugin
[  2%] Built target _hector_gazebo_plugins_generate_messages_check_deps_SetBias
[  2%] Built target hector_gazebo_ros_gps
[  3%] Built target hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic
[  3%] Building CXX object hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_servo_plugin.dir/src/servo_plugin.cpp.o
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosSonar::Load(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:60:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘dynamic_pointer_cast(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr&)’
   sensor_ = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<sensors::RaySensor>(_sensor);
                                                                    ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:60:68: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/common/CommonTypes.hh:24,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/common/Plugin.hh:44,
                 from /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_sonar.h:32,
                 from /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:29:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:808:42: note: template<class T, class U> boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::dynamic_pointer_cast(const boost::shared_ptr<U>&)
 template<class T, class U> shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( shared_ptr<U> const & r ) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
                                          ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:808:42: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:60:68: note:   ‘gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr {aka std::shared_ptr<gazebo::sensors::Sensor>}’ is not derived from ‘const boost::shared_ptr<U>’
   sensor_ = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<sensors::RaySensor>(_sensor);
                                                                    ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:68:49: warning: ‘std::string gazebo::sensors::Sensor::GetWorldName() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/sensors/Sensor.hh:200) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   std::string worldName = sensor_->GetWorldName();
                                                 ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:90:50: error: ‘class gazebo::sensors::RaySensor’ has no member named ‘GetAngleMax’
   range_.field_of_view = std::min(fabs((sensor_->GetAngleMax() - sensor_->GetAngleMin()).Radian()), fabs((sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMax() - sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMin()).Radian()));
                                                  ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:90:75: error: ‘class gazebo::sensors::RaySensor’ has no member named ‘GetAngleMin’
   range_.field_of_view = std::min(fabs((sensor_->GetAngleMax() - sensor_->GetAngleMin()).Radian()), fabs((sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMax() - sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMin()).Radian()));
                                                                           ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:90:116: error: ‘class gazebo::sensors::RaySensor’ has no member named ‘GetVerticalAngleMax’
   range_.field_of_view = std::min(fabs((sensor_->GetAngleMax() - sensor_->GetAngleMin()).Radian()), fabs((sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMax() - sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMin()).Radian()));
                                                                                                                    ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:90:149: error: ‘class gazebo::sensors::RaySensor’ has no member named ‘GetVerticalAngleMin’
   range_.field_of_view = std::min(fabs((sensor_->GetAngleMax() - sensor_->GetAngleMin()).Radian()), fabs((sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMax() - sensor_->GetVerticalAngleMin()).Radian()));
                                                                                                                                                     ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:91:43: warning: ‘double gazebo::sensors::RaySensor::GetRangeMax() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/sensors/RaySensor.hh:103) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   range_.max_range = sensor_->GetRangeMax();
                                           ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:92:43: warning: ‘double gazebo::sensors::RaySensor::GetRangeMin() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/sensors/RaySensor.hh:94) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   range_.min_range = sensor_->GetRangeMin();
                                           ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosSonar::Update()’:
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:141:43: warning: ‘gazebo::physics::MultiRayShapePtr gazebo::sensors::RaySensor::GetLaserShape() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/sensors/RaySensor.hh:253) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   int num_ranges = sensor_->GetLaserShape()->GetSampleCount() * sensor_->GetLaserShape()->GetVerticalSampleCount();
                                           ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:141:88: warning: ‘gazebo::physics::MultiRayShapePtr gazebo::sensors::RaySensor::GetLaserShape() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/sensors/RaySensor.hh:253) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   int num_ranges = sensor_->GetLaserShape()->GetSampleCount() * sensor_->GetLaserShape()->GetVerticalSampleCount();
                                                                                        ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:143:41: warning: ‘gazebo::physics::MultiRayShapePtr gazebo::sensors::RaySensor::GetLaserShape() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/sensors/RaySensor.hh:253) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     double ray = sensor_->GetLaserShape()->GetRange(i);
                                         ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::ServoPlugin::Update()’:
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp:203:25: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     servo[FIRST].joint->SetMaxForce(0, maximumTorque);
                         ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp:205:28: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
       servo[SECOND].joint->SetMaxForce(0, maximumTorque);
                            ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp:207:29: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
         servo[THIRD].joint->SetMaxForce(0, maximumTorque);
                             ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp:211:25: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     servo[FIRST].joint->SetMaxForce(0, 0.0);
                         ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp:213:28: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
       servo[SECOND].joint->SetMaxForce(0, 0.0);
                            ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/servo_plugin.cpp:215:29: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
         servo[THIRD].joint->SetMaxForce(0, 0.0);
                             ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::Update()’:
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:231:25: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     joints[FRONT_LEFT]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                         ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:232:23: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     joints[MID_LEFT]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                       ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:233:24: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     joints[REAR_LEFT]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                        ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:235:26: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     joints[FRONT_RIGHT]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                          ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:236:24: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     joints[MID_RIGHT]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                        ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:237:25: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
     joints[REAR_RIGHT]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                         ^
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosDiffDriveMultiWheel::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.cpp:250:27: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetMaxForce’
         joints_[side][i]->SetMaxForce(0, torque);
                           ^
hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_servo_plugin.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_servo_plugin.dir/src/servo_plugin.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_servo_plugin.dir/src/servo_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6278: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_servo_plugin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_servo_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6243: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/all] Error 2
hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5422: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all] Error 2
hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5457: recipe for target 'hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_multi_wheel.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Base path: /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial
Source space: /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src
Build space: /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build
Devel space: /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/devel
Install space: /home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/paul/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build"
####
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Here is my apt sources file:

```
 % cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main
```

And here is my Debian release information

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:        8.5
Codename:       jessie
```

And here is my gazebo version:

```
 % gazebo --version
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org
```

If it's not possible to run on kinetic, is there an easy way to switch ROS versions on Debian?  It seems like earlier versions are only supported on Ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244776/is-it-possible-to-run-the-hector_quadrotor-demos-in-kinetic?/) by [pcarleton](https://answers.ros.org/users/28117/pcarleton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/23668/jbourne/) on 2016-10-19**:
any update on this?

**Comment by [baraki](https://answers.ros.org/users/27261/baraki/) on 2016-11-04**:
I am having a similar issue on kinetic

**Comment by [shianchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/40422/shianchen/) on 2019-03-15**:
I am trying implement this project too. I launch the project successfully. But i can only control the copter by keyboard. Can anyone tell me how to make the copter fly using SLAM, just like the video shows?
Thank you.

**Comment by [Wajeeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/40286/wajeeh/) on 2019-03-22**:
I'm having issue launching indoor hector slam, did you also had similar problem trying to run the indoor simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering the same thing and found a way to download and build Hector Quadrotor for Kinetic. There is a number of packages to install (using apt-get) and some to clone from their git in a catkin workspace, then it compiles fine. Then there are some options to deactivate (the propulsion and aerodynamics plugins). I've made a script for the whole process. In the end you should be able to run the demo by doing 'roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch'

```
#!/bin/bash

# to execute when in catkin_ws/src folder
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-unique-identifier
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-geographic-info
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-laser-geometry
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf-conversions
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joy

git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor
git clone -b catkin https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models
git clone -b catkin https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam

sed -i -e 's/option(USE_PROPULSION_PLUGIN "Use a model of the quadrotor propulsion system" ON)/option(USE_PROPULSION_PLUGIN "Use a model of the quadrotor propulsion system" OFF)/g' hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/urdf/CMakeLists.txt

sed -i -e 's/option(USE_AERODYNAMICS_PLUGIN "Use a model of the quadrotor aerodynamics" ON)/option(USE_AERODYNAMICS_PLUGIN "Use a model of the quadrotor aerodynamics" OFF)/g' hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/urdf/CMakeLists.txt

# this is to deactivate warnings
sed -i -e 's/add_dependencies(landing_action hector_uav_msgs_generate_message_cpp)//g' hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_actions/CMakeLists.txt

sed -i -e 's/add_dependencies(pose_action hector_uav_msgs_generate_message_cpp)//g' hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_actions/CMakeLists.txt

sed -i -e 's/add_dependencies(takeoff_action hector_uav_msgs_generate_message_cpp)//g' hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_actions/CMakeLists.txt

sed -i -e 's/add_dependencies(hector_quadrotor_controllers hector_uav_msgs_generate_message_cpp)//g' hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controllers/CMakeLists.txt


cd ..
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Kittenator](https://answers.ros.org/users/29537/kittenator/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on 2017-03-09**:
Hi! Thanks! It worked! But the quadrotor just refuse to take off even if I publish  geometry_msgs/Twist messages through topic /cmd_vel. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

**Comment by [Kittenator](https://answers.ros.org/users/29537/kittenator/) on 2017-03-14**:
You have to enable the motors by calling the \enable_motors service :

```
rosservice call \enable_motors true
```

Then you should be able to make it fly !

**Comment by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on 2017-08-29**:
Thanks a lot @Kittenator for this wonderful help! However, once in ran catkin_make, I saw that hector_quadrotot_demo has not been built. Only hector_gazebo, hector_localization, hector_models, hector_quadrotor and hector_slam
Somebody can help me to find out what happens?
Thank you very much for you

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2017-10-06**:
@fabriceN hector_quadrotor_demo is a package of hector_quadrotor.

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2017-10-22**:
Hi, Any idea how i can make this service call in a script using python?

**Comment by [patrick_rice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32992/patrick_rice/) on 2017-12-22**:
I am getting the error that outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch is neither a launch file in pack or a launch file name

**Comment by [patrick_rice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32992/patrick_rice/) on 2017-12-22**:
@lahiruherath, you would need to port the entire script as far as i can tell.

**Comment by [patrick_rice](https://answers.ros.org/users/32992/patrick_rice/) on 2017-12-22**:
My issue was solved by sourcing the setup.bash file myself after running the script.

**Comment by [SMEAC](https://answers.ros.org/users/37699/smeac/) on 2018-09-24**:
Thanks a lot @Kittenator. There does appear to be an error in the sed code given above. In each sed command you need to remove the first hector_quadrotor/ from a CMakeLists.txt location.  e.g. `hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/urdf/CMakeLists.txt`, not `hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor/...`

**Comment by [Wajeeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/40286/wajeeh/) on 2019-03-20**:
I'm getting this error when I am trying to cmake on ros kinetic ubuntu, plz help

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
    CMake Error at /home/wajeeh-ros/catkin_ws/devel/share/hector_quadrotor_model/cmake/hector_quadrotor_modelConfig.cmake:148 (message):
      Project 'hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins' tried to find library
      '-lpthread'.  The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.
      Did you compile project 'hector_quadrotor_model'? Did you find_package() it
      before the subdirectory containing its code is included?
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
      hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
    
     --Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/wajeeh-ros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "/home/wajeeh-ros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
```